# How to unlock Motorola Atrix 4G for other carriers?

Tags: sim-unlocking, motorola-atrix-4g

I bought a Motorola Atrix 4G MB860 and discovered that it is locked. I received an unlock code from AT&T but I receive the message "network unlock code unsuccessful" which according to AT&T means that it is locked to their network.

After reading a little it seems that I have two options, neither of which I am familiar with:

- To wipe the radio on the device.
- Sign up for a service on the Internet that claim to unlock the device for me (can someone recommend a reliable service)

Please advise what is the better option or if there are other options, and provide directions on how to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

If your unit was originally sold by AT&T and the unlocking code provided by AT&T did not work - then it means that the invalid unlocking attempts counter was exhausted on this unit. No other "unlocking service on the Internet" will be able to help you.

"Wiping the radio" option (i.e. flashing incompatible baseband processor software, so it would reset internal settings including subsidy lock) would also wipe out the unique phasing (i.e. calibration) data from the unit - which would result in degraded signal reception.

The bottom line... if I were you - I would ask for my money back.